# Probability that the eighth person to play a video game will be the fifth person to enjoy it

Tags: probability

> If the probability is .75 that person will play a video game, find the 
>   probability that the 8th person to play the game will be the 5th person 
>   who enjoys watching what's being played.

P(Success) = .75

P(Success') = .25

P(8th person to play the game will be the 5th person 
                         who enjoys watching what's being played)

= P(7th person to play the game will be the 4th person 
    who enjoys watching what's being played)

= binompdf(7,.75,4) * (.75) =  .12977 <-- answer

Comment: No your answer is not right.

Comment: @ZacharySelk I think I found my mistake, forgot to multiply .75.  Is it correct now?

Comment: Your claim that the seventh person to play the game will be the fourth person to enjoy it is not necessarily true. What matters is that exactly four of the first seven people enjoy it and that the eighth person enjoys it.

Answer (score 2):

For the eighth person to be the fifth person to enjoy the game, exactly four of the first seven people who play must enjoy the game and the eighth person must enjoy the game.  Therefore, the desired probability is 
$$\binom{7}{4}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^4\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^3 \cdot \frac{3}{4} \approx 0.129776000977$$
so your answer is correct.

However, it is not necessarily the case that the seven person to play the game will be the fourth person who enjoys the game.